# Probability of 3 different factors

Tags: probability

As a probability newbie, I'm struggling to understand a basic principle in a question I'm facing, which is:

> Researchers are trying to study the following factors for one's success in school:
>
> 1. High grade in the SAT exams
> 2. High grades in High School
> 3. High grade in Probability class
>
> Given that:
>
> 1. For each one of the three, the probability for a student to have this factor and none of the others is 0.1
> 2. For each two of the tree, the probability of a student to have these 2 factors, and not the third is 0.12
> 3. The probability of a student to have all three factors, given that he has (1) and (3) is 1/3
>
> We'll mark as X the following incident: "A student has all three factors"
>
> Calculate $\mathbb{P}(X)$

Well, I understand that I should use these formula:

$$
\mathbb{P}(A \cap B \cap C | A \cap B) = \frac{\mathbb{P}( (A \cap B \cap C) \cap (A \cap B))}{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B \cap C)}{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}
$$

But, for calculating $ \mathbb{P}(A \cap B) $ they did the following:

$ \mathbb{P}(A \cap B) =  \mathbb{P}(A \cap B \cap C) + \mathbb{P}(A \cap B \cap \bar{C}) $

I don't understand why the need to sum both incident where the student has A, B and C and the incident where the student has A,B but not C.

Why it is not sufficient to calculate only the second incident?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a student has both $A$ and $B$, then the student may or may not have $C$. We need to account for both possibilities when calculating the probability of having $A$ and $B$, so we need both terms.